# Do sink drain basket strainers have to match the sink brand?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink, plumbing-fixture

I am planning on purchasing a certain brand of fireclay sink (need a specific sink because of unusual size). It has a 3.5 inch drain hole.

On their website, the manufacturer claims you must use one of three of their own brand basket strainers. Needless to say, theirs cost $50 to $80 as opposed to $15 to $25 for generic brands.

Do some sinks really need brand-matched drain parts or are all 3.5 inch drains standard?

Comment: I'd get one of each, and return the one that doesn't fit.  In my experience they are standard size, but it's entirely possible that a manufacturer made theirs proprietary.

Comment: I have never known that a proprietary drain needed. Pretty much all kitchen sink drains are 3 1/2", and have a threaded section to accommodate thicker sink material. I don't know what you sink looks like, but I have mounted a number of ceramic farm sinks that weigh too much and it took no special drain.

Comment: @Jack Sounds like an answer to me.